# LaTex not showing the URLS in the bibliography

Tags: latex

I'm having a LaTex issue.
I'm using a shareLatex template that some mates developed.
Everything goes fine in the bibliography until I see that it is not including the URLs. My citations are as follows:

```
 @misc{wikipediaWatchList,
   author = {VVAA},
   title = {Help:Watchlist},
   url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Watchlist},
   howpublished = "\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Watchlist}",
   note = "[Web; accedido el 08-05-2019]"
 }
```

But it won't show the URL at all.
Any tips on this issue will be highly appreciated.
The content of my bibliography configuration file is the following:

```
\def\ficherosBibliografia{}
\newcommand{\setBibFiles}[1]{
\def\ficherosBibliografia{#1}
}


\def\citaBibliografia{}
\newcommand{\setCitaBibliografia}[1]{
\def\citaBibliografia{#1}
}

\newcommand{\makeBib}{

\let\oldbibpreamble\bibpreamble

\def\bibpreamble{%
\oldbibpreamble

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\label{bibliografia}
\citaBibliografia
}


\begingroup
\spanishdeactivate{~}

\bibliographystyle{TeXiS/TeXiS}

\bibliography{\ficherosBibliografia}
\endgroup

}
```

Comment: Whether or not the url is shown depends entirely on the bibliography style you use. Please make a minimal working example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I just added what my bibliography config style contains.

Comment: Please make a compilable example and not just code fragments

Comment: Also please add `TeXiS.bst`

Comment: I think it is too long to include it. Are you sure you can't answer the question with the info above please?

Comment: I'm not interested in your whole document, just a short test document that replicates the problem. See [mre] for instructions how to make one

Comment: If the bst file is too long to include, you could use pastebin.com, github etc.